# oracle php oci prcedure failed

Tags: php, oracle, stored-procedures, oracle-call-interface

I am getting the following error, When I tried to execute `GET_Card_TRANS` procedure:

```
[code] => 6550

[message] => ORA-06550: line 6, column 21:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "" when expecting one of the following:

   . ( ) , * @ % & = - + < / > at in is mod remainder not rem =>
<an exponent (**)> <> or != or ~= >= <= <> and or like like2
  like4 likec between || indicator multiset member submultiset

[offset] => 155

[sqltext] => BEGIN 
            WEB_SHOW.GET_Card_TRANS(
                :User_Id,
                :Pswd,
                :vcard_id
                :sdate
                :EDATE
                :Vcond
                :CARD_TRANS_data
            );
        END;
```

This is the PHP code:

```
<?php

// Connect to database
$conn = oci_connect("xxx", "yyy", "aaaa:bb/cc", 'dd');

if (!$conn) {
    $e = oci_error($conn);
    print_r($e);
    exit ("Connection failed.");
}

$user_id    = 'demo';
$password   = 'password';
$vcard_id   = '1-0';
$start_date = '01-01-2016';
$end_date   = '01-01-2016';
$condition  = '1';

$sql = "BEGIN 
            web_show.GET_Card_TRANS(
                :User_Id,
                :Pswd,
                :vcard_id
                :sdate
                :EDATE
                :Vcond
                :CARD_TRANS_data
            );
        END;";

$stmt = oci_parse($conn, $sql);

oci_bind_by_name($stmt, ':User_Id',  $user_id    );
oci_bind_by_name($stmt, ':Pswd',     $password   );
oci_bind_by_name($stmt, ':vcard_id', $vcard_id   );
oci_bind_by_name($stmt, ':sdate',    $start_date );
oci_bind_by_name($stmt, ':EDATE',    $end_date   );
oci_bind_by_name($stmt, ':Vcond',    $condition  );

// Create a new cursor resource
$curs = oci_new_cursor($conn);

// Bind the cursor resource to the Oracle argument
oci_bind_by_name($stmt,":CARD_TRANS_data",$curs,-1,OCI_B_CURSOR);


if (!oci_execute($stmt)) {
    $e = oci_error($stmt);
    print_r($e);
    exit("Procedure Failed.");
}

// Execute the cursor
if (!oci_execute($curs, OCI_DEFAULT)) {
    $e = oci_error($curs);
    print_r($e);
    exit("Execute cursor Failed.");
}

while (($row = oci_fetch_array($curs, OCI_ASSOC+OCI_RETURN_NULLS)) != false) {
    print_r($row);
    //echo $row['FIRST_NAME'] . "<br />\n";
}

oci_free_statement($stmt);
oci_free_statement($curs);
oci_close($conn);

?>
```

Comment: seems like you have an error in your procedure, can you provide more details ?

Comment: Please show code of  `GET_Card_TRANS`

Comment: Difficult to say without GET_Card_TRANS code, but you may be missing some parens or semicolon somewhere

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Missing commas, perhaps?

This:

```
$sql = "BEGIN 
            web_show.GET_Card_TRANS(
                :User_Id,
                :Pswd,
                :vcard_id
                :sdate
                :EDATE
                :Vcond
                :CARD_TRANS_data
            );
        END;"
```

;

Should instead be:

```
$sql = "BEGIN 
            web_show.GET_Card_TRANS(
                :User_Id,
                :Pswd,
                :vcard_id,
                :sdate,
                :EDATE,
                :Vcond,
                :CARD_TRANS_data
            );
        END;";
```